# For loop is looping too much

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I am looping through a for loop to perform a simple calculation.  The results of each iteration are stored into an array.  The array has the correct number of elements but the output has exponentially too many elements.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Fibonacci.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script>
(function($) {
    $.fn.writeText = function(content) {
        var contentArray = content,
        current = 0,
        elem = this;
    setInterval(function() {
        if(current < contentArray.length) {
            elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++]);                
            }
        }, 1000);
    };    
})(jQuery); 
</script>
</head>
<body>  
<script>
    document.write(getArray());
$(document).ready(function($){      
    var contentArray = getArray();
    $('#calculations').writeText(contentArray);
}); 
</script>
<h3>Fibonacci Sequence:</h3>
<p id='calculations'></p>
```

External JS:

```
var result;
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
var resultArray = [x,y];

function FibonacciCalculation(){
    for(var i = 2; i < 5; i++){     
        result = x + y;
        x = y;
        y = result;
        resultArray.push(result);
    }
}

function getArray(){
    FibonacciCalculation();
    return resultArray;
}

window.onload = function(){
    FibonacciCalculation();
};
```

Comment: @Rooster: So? It's perfectly fine to ask about homework here, if you're asking for help with a solution you've clearly made an effort on.

Comment: You called `getArray` two times the `<script>` part of the html so I guess resultArray is pushed with fibonnacci two times ?

Comment: @ Will: Your browser has a debugger built into it, you can open it through the menus or (probably) with either F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I (or Cmd+Shift+I on a Mac). Your best bet for figuring this out is to use the debugger to walk through the code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not complaining, just playing iSpy

Comment: You're running `FibonacciCalculation()` multiple times: you run it in the `window.onload` handler, in `document.write(getArray())`, and again in `$(document).ready()`. Each of them adds to the array.

Comment: @ Will: Side note, because I'm sure it isn't the main problem, but note that the function you've set up to run with `setInterval` will keep getting called, forever, even once `current` is `>= contentArray.length`. It won't do anything once that's the case, but it'll keep getting called. Either store the return value from `setInterval` and use that with `clearInterval`, or use a series of individually-scheduled `setTimeout` calls instead.

Comment: @Rooster Not homework sir.  I'm actually just messing around learning JavaScript/JQuery and this was an example presented to me when I was expressing interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called getArray two times the `<script>` part of the html so resultArray is called several time (2 and 4th line).

```
<script>
    document.write(getArray());
    $(document).ready(function($){      
        var contentArray = getArray();
        $('#calculations').writeText(contentArray);
    }); 
</script>
```

Also you should correct the `<` to `>` in your if condition because it seems that it will always be true.

```
 if(current < contentArray.length) {
     elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++]);                
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset your `resultArray` every time you run `FibonacciCalculation` function:

```
function FibonacciCalculation() {
   resultArray = [x, y]
   // ...
```